# Why doesn't the submitted form submit to database WP?

Tags: database, wordpress

I am trying to submit data, retrieved through a custom form, into the post type 'posts'.

How ever it isn't working. It var_dumps, but it when I go to 'posts' I can see it hasn't been uploaded.

'Posts' is not custom, I also tried doing it through a custom post type which I registered, But it also didn't work.

**My formHandler.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $berichtnaam = $_POST['berichtnaam'];
    $categories = array('kat', 'hond', 'slang');
    $categorie = $_POST['categorie'];
    $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
    $bericht = $_POST['bericht'];
    $post_content = array($categorie, $bericht);
    


    var_dump($berichtnaam);
    var_dump($foto);
    var_dump($post_content);

    $blog_post = (array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($berichtnaam),
        'post_content' => $post_content
    ) );

 

  wp_insert_post($blog_post);
  
}
```

**My form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/formHandler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Berichtnaam</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Geen titel" name="berichtnaam">
                    </div>

            
                    <label for="select-field">Categorie</label>
                        <select class="form-select form-control" id="select-field" aria-label="Default select example" name="categorie">
                            <option selected>Geen categorie</option>
                            <option value="kat">Kat</option>
                            <option value="hond">Hond</option>
                            <option value="slang">Slang</option>
                        </select>



                    <div class="mb-3" id="file_field">
                            <label for="uploadFoto" id="input_file">
                                <i class="fi fi-rr-camera"></i><span id="upload_btn">Kies bestand</span>
                            </label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="uploadFoto" onchange="showFileName()" name="foto">
                            <p id="fileSelected"></p>
                            <p id="fileUnSelected"></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formGroupExampleInput2" class="form-label">Bericht</label><br>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" name="bericht"></textarea>
                            </div>

                    <button id="card-L" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Bericht aanmaken</button>
                </form>
```

I've tried it like this, which was answered in a similar question:

```
$blog_post = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($berichtnaam),
        'post_content' => $post_content
    ) );

  $post_type = 'blogpost_vero';

  $query = "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts SET post_type='".$post_type."' WHERE id='".$blog_post."' LIMIT 1";
  
  GLOBAL $wpdb; 
  
  $wpdb->query($query);
```

***Note: I am not yet submitting the $_FILES because I had to figure this out yet.***

**Eventually I want to upload what is submitted through the form and then display this on the home page and blog archive page, inside of cards with a thumbnail. This is not going online, this is just as an exercise for (hopefully) a new workplace**

Any help is appreciated greatly! Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: maybe this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126835/post-status-publish-not-working) would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply! unfortunatly it did not do anything after I added: add_post_meta( $blog_post, '_wti_like_count', 0, true );
        add_post_meta( $blog_post, '_wti_unlike_count', 0, true );
        add_post_meta( $blog_post, '_wti_total_count', 0, true );

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should do a little more error checking.

Try this:

```php
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $blog_post, true);
if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) {
    print_r ( $post_id );
} else {
  /* post_id has the ID of the new post */
}
```

This should help you determine what happened to your post.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I've put this in my code, but now it isn't even showing the var_dumps. In source code and in element inspect it shows nothing that may answer to what is going wrong